# How to programmatically add different actions and colours for on/off state to a Button

Tags: ios, swift, button

I have a button that I would like to use to show and hide a `UIView`. If you click the button, the `UIView` is shown. If you click again, the `UIView` should be hidden again.

This is the code I have:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
myView.hidden = true
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
        myView.hidden = false
}
```

Adding to this, I'm looking to give the button a green color when it's tapped, and the normal blue when it's tapped again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
        myView.hidden = false
}
```

to

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
        myView.hidden = !myView.hidden
        if myView.hidden {
           sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }else{
           sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply toggle the `hidden` property:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
    // Toggle the view
    myView.hidden = !myView.hidden

    // Update the button color
    if myView.hidden {
        // make button blue
    } else {
        // make button green
    }
}
```

I'm not fluent in Swift so I don't know the syntax to set the button's color but the above should point you in the right direction.